# ngModel doesn't work when loading the page

Tags: angular

I am trying to show a particular div based on the input field value on-load itself. the value set on the input field from my angular service. But with the [(ngModel)] it doesn't bind on load. Is there any way i can achieve this using angular 2.

```
<input id="showValue" value="1" [(ngModel)]="showValue">
{{showValue}}
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="show==1 || 'showValue'==1">
                <h5>BACKGROUND</h5>{{showValue}} 
</div>
```

Comment: did you import FormsModule

Comment: What is `'showValue'==1"` supposed to do? That will always be false.

Comment: showValue will have a value from my service. it should check the value and show the div on load

Comment: But `'showValue'==1` compares the string `'showValue'` with the integer `1`. I guess it should be `showValue==1` (without the quotes)

Answer (score 1):

Set instead the value of `showValue`

```
class MyComponent {
  showValue:string;
  constructor() {
    this.showValue = 1;
  }
}
```

```
<input id="showValue" [(ngModel)]="showValue">
{{showValue}}
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="show==1 || showValue==1">
                <h5>BACKGROUND</h5>{{showValue}} 
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply this is the same i'm doing from my service the value element i put to show an example

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the comment. Does this mean you don't want to do this, or you can't do this? What are the reasons? AFAIK `value="1"` won't have any effect in your example, because `ngModel` overwrites it with the value of `showValue`, when `ngModel` is initialized.

Comment: Sorry i mean to say that i did the same and doesn't work for me. i think i'm doing something somewhere wrong

Comment: Thank you. now its working
 "this.showValue = localStorage.getItem("showValue");" this was setting to 0 when i load the page.
is this a good way of doing this with localStorage. Can you please advice me

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, but without more context I can't tell for sure. If it does what you want, it should be fine.

Comment: Thank you @gunter Zochbauer

Comment: From my service how can i update the value of constructor variable "showValue" of different component. now it works only on for the first load.

Comment: I can't tell without any context. If you add your code to the question I can have another look.

Comment: this is my service code 
switch (buttonName) {
case "0x01010000":
//Here i want to set component showValue to 1 then i don't have to use the localStorage
                            showValue = 1;
                            $('#showValue').prop("value",1);
                            break;
                        case "0x01020000":
                            console.log('showValue==2');
                            showValue = 2;   
                            $('#showValue').prop("value",2);
                            break;
                        default:

Answer (score 0):

Local storage is not a good way to do so you should user services then set values in scope variables.

Comment: can i use `this.showValue = connectService.showValue;` for getting value from service to component